# bigquery: what are the difference between `string_value` vs `string`

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigquery, what are the difference between `string_value` vs `string`?

```
data.to_value is a record.
data.to_value.string_value
data.to_value.string
data.to_value.double_value
data.to_value.double
```

And there are `double_value` vs `double`.

I did not find related documents. wired.

thanks

Comment: it is the same as difference between column name (for example int_value) and column's data type (for example INT64), so those `string_value, double_value` are just fields' names and they could be name differently but they named this way to help users to be more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

It could be a specific case for how the data.to_value record is defined.
It is very difficult to say without looking at some sample data.
Below example is from Firebase where you can see string_value, int_value, double_value, etc. They are just column names in this case.

```
SELECT 
  MAX(if(param.key = "value", param.value.int_value, NULL)) AS score,
  MAX(if(param.key = "board", param.value.string_value, NULL)) AS board_type
FROM (
  SELECT event_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, param
  FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_20181003`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param
  WHERE event_name = "level_complete_quickplay" 
  AND (param.key = "value" OR param.key = "board")
) 
GROUP BY user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp
```